Why were a good amount of comments from a question removed?
Why were a good amount of comments from this question removed?
My question (in the comments) was reasonable.
One more question where IMHO is appropriate to comment about different approach.

A fairly common complaint we get about the network as a whole is -well folks asking "why are you doing it this way, why not do it another way?"
Sometimes Frame challenges are useful - but in this case especially with a new user, its a distraction.
Basically the comments weren't really helpful in helping the user actually find a solution in the context of the post, and were deleted to keep things managable/less confusing.

I do not agree, if you directly answer to the user he/she will never learn. If you point him/her to something which will do better work this is helpful.

But what are you teaching? That people will suggest alternatives and not really follow up?

No alternative, suggest better (proper)  way.

@RomeoNinov - If a comment answer(s) the question then it should be deleted, and an answer should be submitted. Answers should NOT be submitted as a comment

It wasn't an answer. It was somewhere along the lines of "why use samba? NFS is better"

@JourneymanGeek, no!!! The comment was something like: "why use samba when you can use NFS". I never said NFS is better!

@Ramhound, you insult me. Do you think for 9 years in this site I did not get this rule?

@RomeoNinov Well, that's how I see a new user reading it. See also my question on rclone - where you suggested wget, despite the fact that (in theory) rclone can also upload - I get trying to be helpful, and other approaches but it also can distract from the problem at hand.

@JourneymanGeek, this is exactly I try t say. IMHO it's better to teach users, not giving them then answer of specific question (of course this is not applicable everywhere). My understanding is if we give just answers we are not different from AI. Which will be pity...

@RomeoNinov - Are you seriously accusing me of insulting you? I am not insulting you. I mean you are asking why temporary comments were delete, the obvious reason, is they were reported as "no longer necessary" and a moderator deleted it. Your first comment to this answer, suggests that you attempted to answer the question, with a comment instead of an answer.

@Ramhound, no this is not an answer. Just want to make the mod why his answer maybe is wrong. And my first comment a paraphrased parable from the bible.

My answer isn't wrong. There's no answer. I'm still trying to figure out why OP's smb install isn't working without great access to an OS X machine :D

@JourneymanGeek, I talk about this answer, not in this one in the link :)

While I don't pretend to infallibility, I'd say the answer answers the 'why' from the perspective and expectations of a moderator who would delete such a comment.  In this specific case it explains why the determination to delete the comments were made. Whether it was the right determination in this case or universally is left as an exercise to the reader then :D
